# os.path points to incorrect location with Pyinstaller in multiple file imports

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have two python files `main.py` and `aux.py` located in the same directory.

`main.py` contains the following code:

```
import aux
print "aux imported"
```

`aux.py` contains the following code:

```
import os
current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print current_path
```

Now, when I bundle main.py to .exe using `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` and try running the main.exe which gets produced, I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\vimanyua\AppData\Local\Temp\3\_MEI90~1
aux imported
```

As can be seen, pyinstaller using a temp folder to locate my aux.py which is creating a lot of issue for me because `aux.py` in my actual code reads other sibling files located in its current directory. If I just create a .exe for `aux.py` like `pyinstaller --onefile aux.py` - it outputs the correct path

`C:\Users\vimanyua\Documents\pyinstaller test\dist`

I read the documentation at [this link](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html) and as I want to run `aux.py` first, I trie creating an exe file like this -

`pyinstaller --onefile --runtime-hook=aux.py main.py`

It creates a single `main.exe` which runs `aux.py` first and then runs `main.exe`. When it runs aux.py I get following output:

```
C:\Users\vimanyua\Documents\pyinstaller test\dist
C:\Users\vimanyua\AppData\Local\Temp\3\_MEI90~1
aux imported
```

My `main.py` actually uses multiple functions/variables from `aux.py` so I cannot get rid of the `import aux` statement in `main.py` and I really do not want to merge the code into a single file.

Can anyone please provide me any guidance? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your project file tree is set up correctly as a python *package*? See https://hackernoon.com/the-one-stop-guide-to-easy-cross-platform-python-freezing-part-1-c53e66556a0a for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use `__file__` to refer to path, please use `sys._MEIPASS`.
To refer to the sibling of the aux.py file, please use this helper function:

```
import sys
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

For example, if in your `aux.py` you want to read sibling files named `readme.txt`, you can refer as:

```
filepath = resource_path('readme.txt')
```

See the docs [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file-and-sys-meipass).

Comment: `_MEIPASS` starts with an underscore character (`_`) - I believe it is not meant to be exposed and consumed directly. Are you sure it's safe to use?

Comment: It's the way to access temp folder created by pyinstaller. I can't guarantee it's safe or not, but I never heard people complaining about this.

Answer (score 0):

try packaging without --onefile, that worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).